# Compare two values in the same column python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare two values in the same column in a `pandas.DataFrame`.
If the two values are different I want to create a new value.
My code looks like this:

```
def f(x, var1, var2):
            if (x[var1].shift(1) != x[var1]):
                x[var2] = 1
            else:
                x[var2] = 0
            return x  

sdf['2008':'2009'].apply(lambda x: f(x, 'ROW1','ROW2'),axis = 1)
```

Unfortunatly, this one doesn't work.  I get the following error massage

> 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'shift'", 'occurred at index 2008-01-01 00:00:00'

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are `row1` and `ROW2` names for columns on pandas?? I see you have `2008:2009`, do these columns include the `row1` and `row2`??

Comment: provide data sample. And `shift()` can be applied on `pandas.Series` not on single value.

Comment: @Onyambu Yes, that are names for columns (I forgot the '' for Row1). The dataframe contains dayli data from 2008-01-01 to 2009-31-01

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
df0 = df.shift()

df['Row2'] = np.where(df0['Row1']!=df['Row1'], 1, 0)
```

**EDIT**:

As @jpp suggested in comments:

```
df['Row2'] = (df0['Row1']!=df['Row1']).astype(int)
```

Comment: Or `(df0['Row1']!=df['Row1']).astype(int)`.